# Filter table data, and show table head

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a big table with multiple table heads.  I have a simple `js` function to filter table data, but I need to make it so that it shows the table head section too. I added `tbody` and `tr` tags to my function but now it searches data in `table` but shows every `thead` section. How can I get that it shows only the specific `thead` section which contains searched `tr` element?

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTable tbody tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
   
<div class="col-md d-inline">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Meklēt.." id="myInput">
</div>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Information about department</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name - It</td>
      <td>Phone - 1111111</td>
      <td>E-mail - mail@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead class="bg-primary">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Information about department 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name - Finance</td>
      <td>Phone - 1111112</td>
      <td>E-mail - finance@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td>Name - Finance2</td>
      <td>Phone - 1111113</td>
      <td>E-mail - finance2@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not valid HTML to have multiple `<thead>` within a `<table>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below approach with data attribute `data-group` to group `thead` and `tbody` into separate groups. That would help to recognize element sections and find string matches in groups easily.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim();
    $("#myTable thead").each(function() {
      var group = $(this).data("group")
      var isTheadMatched = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1

      var selector = `tbody[data-group='${group}'] tr`
      var allRows = $('#myTable').find(selector);
      var isAnyRowMatched = false;

      for (var row of $(allRows)) {
        const isRowMatched = isTheadMatched || $(row).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1
        $(row).toggle(isRowMatched);
        if ($(row).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) {
          isAnyRowMatched = true;
        }
      }

      $(this).toggle(isTheadMatched || isAnyRowMatched)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-md d-inline">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" placeholder="Meklēt.." id="myInput">
</div>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead class="bg-primary" data-group="1">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Information about department</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-group="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Name - It</td>
      <td>Phone - 1111111</td>
      <td>E-mail - mail@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <thead class="bg-primary" data-group="2">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3">Information about department 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-group="2">
    <tr>
      <td>Name - Finance</td>
      <td>Phone - 1111112</td>
      <td>E-mail - finance@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name - Finance2</td>
      <td>Phone - 1111113</td>
      <td>E-mail - finance2@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a good solution but not what exactly is needed.  This shows entire tbody section, for exaple if info department 2 would have two `<td>` it would show both, but we need to show only the one who is being searched.

Comment: Could you update that data structure in your question too? I can help you to find a suitable solution @Maaverick

Comment: I updated my question, now if you apply your `js` it will show all `tr` tags for `tbody`. But I need it to match exactly the one being searched. 
Also big thanks for your help.

Comment: I modified the code for the sake of your requirement, @Maaverick

Comment: Thank you this works very good. I have only one question is it possible to make it work for `thead` too ? For example - if I search `Information about department 2` `thead` then it shows me every `<td>` under it and appropriate `thead`?

Comment: I modify my entire answer with custom data attribute, you can check it out again, @Maaverick